# Unmatched events on Event Grid

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I have a Logic App that sets up a subscriptions in Event Grid with the Wait for resource event occurs trigger.

Basically the logic app is triggered by a http request - sends a message on service bus - register subscription and wait for event. I have a custom service that publishes the event to event grid.

Most of the times this works well but from time to time the event is not received by the logic app. When that happens I get an "unmatched" event in event grid.

As a test I have added code in my event publishing service to retrieve all subscriptions from Event Grid and dump it to a log file before I publish the event, and I can see that the subscription is there and have a state of "Succeeded".

I have done these tests without any filters.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: So you are creating the event grid subscription dynamically when the logic app is invoked?

Comment: Yes, not explicitly but that is what the Wait for resource event occurs action does

Comment: Initial thoughts are that it’s a timing issue, does the subscription need to be created dynamically? Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish at a gig level?

Comment: I use Logic Apps to orchestrate work that needs to be run in a particular order. The work is done by 2 different Windows services. So Logic Apps publishes an event for Start Work X via Service Bus and then waits for an event Work X Completed that is received via Event Grid and then continues with Start Work Y and so forth. The subscription is dynamic because Logic Apps registers a webhook for each event type.